# how to remove buttons off of a message discord

Tags: python, discord, pycord

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
message = await ctx.send("**TEST**\n**IS THIS WORKING?**")
await asyncio.sleep(3)
button = Button(style = discord.ButtonStyle.green, emoji = "◀", custom_id = "button")
view = View()
view.add_item(button)

async def button_callback(interaction):
    await message.edit(content="**edited message and removed buttons!**")

button.callback = button_callback

await ctx.send("test", view=view)
```

so far when it edits the message to "edited message and removed buttons" the buttons arent removed, how can i make it so the buttons are removed when it edits to that?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set `view=None` when you edit your message (or if you only want a few buttons removed, create a new view without those buttons and set `view` to that).